# Typescript - Processing Large JSON file with filters and sort

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I have the following json schema to process using Typescript (file with 100 MB of entries).

```
[
   {
      "firstName":"Emma",
      "lastName":"Sall",
      "country":"US",
      "email":"test@hotmail.com",
      "dob":"1944-05-05T13:14:32.526Z",
      "mfa":"SMS",
      "amt":962169704,
      "createdDate":"2020-08-15T20:07:24.157Z",
      "referredBy":null
   },
   {
      "firstName":"Darren",
      "lastName":"test",
      "country":"ES",
      "email":"test334@yahoo.com",
      "dob":"1944-02-11T19:44:58.715Z",
      "mfa":"SMS",
      "amt":239723064,
      "createdDate":"2020-07-12T12:39:47.553Z",
      "referredBy":null
   },
...
   ...
      ...
]
```

I'm having this error when sorting the array at these two lines (**full code below**):

```
a[accountSearchCriteria.sortField] <
b[accountSearchCriteria.sortField]
```

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Account'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Account'.`

I'm using the following code to process the file `main.ts`:

```
import fs from 'fs';
const accountSearchCriteria: AccountSearchCriteria = {
                country: 'CA',
                mfa: 'SMS',
                name: 'TEST',
                sortField: 'amt'
            };
const jsonPath = './test/src.json';
        const rawAccounts = fs.readFileSync(jsonPath, 'utf-8');
        let accounts: Account[] = JSON.parse(rawAccounts);
        if (accountSearchCriteria) {
            if (accountSearchCriteria.name) {
                accounts = accounts.filter(
                    account =>
                        account.firstName.toLowerCase() ===
                            accountSearchCriteria.name.toLowerCase() ||
                        account.lastName.toLowerCase() ===
                            accountSearchCriteria.name.toLowerCase()
                );
            }
            if (accountSearchCriteria.country) {
                accounts = accounts.filter(
                    account =>
                        account.country.toLowerCase() ===
                        accountSearchCriteria.country.toLowerCase()
                );
            }
            if (accountSearchCriteria.mfa) {
                accounts = accounts.filter(
                    account => account.mfa === accountSearchCriteria.mfa
                );
            }
            if (accountSearchCriteria.sortField) {
                 accounts.sort((a, b) =>
                     a[accountSearchCriteria.sortField] <
                     b[accountSearchCriteria.sortField]
                         ? -1
                         : 1
                 );
            }
            return accounts;
        }
        return accounts;
```

The interface is defined as following `account.ts`:

```
export interface Account {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    country: string;
    email: string;
    dob: string;
    mfa?: MFA;
    amt: number;
    createdDate: string;
    referredBy?: string;
}
export enum MFA {
    SMS = 'SMS',
    TOTP = 'TOTP'
}

export interface AccountSearchCriteria {
    country?: string;
    mfa?: string;
    name?: string;
    sortField?: string;
}
```

Also, the code is taking long time to process the file I want to read, which its 100 MB, I tested it against a small file, and it worked well. Is there any faster way to improve the code and make it more efficient?

Comment: The type of `sortField` is `string | undefined`, but is narrowed to just `string` by the time you are doing the `a[...] < b[...]` comparison. The reason TS is complaining is that `a` is not an object that can take an arbitrary string as a key. `a[arbitraryString]` is not allowed. To make it work, you have 3 options. 1) Make `a` generically indexable using an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) 2) Make `a` generically indexable using [the `Record` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)

Comment: 3) change the type of `sortField` to be something like `keyof Account` or somehow otherwise make sure that the `sortField` is only typed as valid keys of the `Account` interface. This is probably your best option because allowing arbitrary strings in your `Account` interface is not the greatest idea (even though it may technically work)

Comment: @nullromo thanks a lot for the comments, can you give me an example of the option no. 3 please?

Comment: Yes, I will post an answer soon.

Comment: @nullromo thanks a lot .. also, not sure if there's a way to improve it to read bigger files .. as its taking a very long time to process them

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about how to speed that up. Nothing jumps out at me immediately. I think this is kind of 2 questions in one, so maybe you should separate them out on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly simplified example with comments

```js
export interface Account {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    country: string;
    email: string;
    dob: string;
    mfa?: MFA;
    amt: number;
    createdDate: string;
    referredBy?: string;
}
export enum MFA {
    SMS = 'SMS',
    TOTP = 'TOTP'
}

export interface AccountSearchCriteria {
    country?: string;
    mfa?: string;
    name?: string;
    sortField?: keyof Account; // here I made sortField into a key of Account
}

const accountSearchCriteria: AccountSearchCriteria = {
  sortField: 'amt'
};

const doThing = (accounts: Account[]) => {
  // make sure the sortField is defined
  if(!accountSearchCriteria.sortField) {
    return;
  }
  const sortField = accountSearchCriteria.sortField; // sortField has type keyof Account
  accounts.sort((a, b) => {
    const aField = a[sortField]; // here you can access the field no problem
    // The type of aField is string | number | undefined because those are all the possible values for an attribute of an Account.
    return a[sortField] < b[sortField] ? -1 : 1 // here you have an issue because at least one of the attributes in the Account interface is possibly undefined.
    // so you need to determine how exactly you want to handle this
  });
  return accounts;
}
```

Here is a link to the code on [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=89&pln=33&pc=53#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQW2wgFcU4BvAKDlrnQSgGcYA5TAW2AC44WpkAcwDcNOgBtMLdl178hounGJkYUAJ5y1CsbWAdMCcVoFIRuuABMIAIxM6lHLAH5eAWQBi+RXU4xeSCQcNmg+tNhQwJiolgAi0Tx82mZhcJHoaJGWAELqrkmm5gC+VKCQsHDAgRxwnviUFgDKbo1wALxwAOTNjZ0ANBYAKgDygwAK7V0j451UJaXg0PDIqBg4eIQqKI1RUNgAFgDCAqsImA1KW2p59ikWTpj58ndKSJzAT8nmSkxLHgjAcSWfIAa2A6gg6AIRFIKGEcAA9Ai4Ps0HgAJJwAyWPC-WD-QGWRAoCBwc5g9RwSHQq5zKhUYhIFhkmGqHaYPZHE5oM68TawmDsznHBCnc4dai0PEwAlA3idPyzIqiBkQJnwayDfZCSYAChwVyYfNZKAA2gBdACU7QAfBdEciDGC+CRInAYKi+H8AUDEEwrMAGEhgJYxAh0LqAIQGgVCg4isUAOmlsss1sldEiMFdSB8JXCauZKZ9RI6MbZu3j3IEmGT3sJ8KRXvxJZRUnd6jAeAp1P5qjE5ZQTDrsF1+r6cBs1radozBfVZNTk0wpuLhPNjeRqLdEJIykwSBZuCY-o9eAYhLgSFJYCgtnE+gsTa1eBgnbw1MwS4Q-uegjgAA+V5BCEUCAXAZA4kGIaTsA2CYCQTCvvsEBIWSbqYOI4jup6kAnggNgPnAABumEkMA-roNAZKHtE2g2CQqBUlCB40gKiYWFmOZkqu9ZAuacAADyTrxLbrnAzhwAAtAAjHAvByU2254LubbEXgrE-kw5GwfBiEafAD5SPAaoflCZ5kjA9GMRRxI4RsJrLCgaBYLgfpwHhTAEeIlKQYGyAhhxShNr8cCqcGMEwKSOKrBwAUohAADulQgDgMA+WFpBwIlB7wFFbZIJYREej+YhFJaPhcVAtGOUwohFEAA)

You can use that to hover over stuff and see the types clearly.